# Why the validation red boxes in a ObservableCollection appear in the Top Left Corner of the container?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having a problem with validation in textboxes that I will try to reproduce in a simple way.
I am using an ObservableColletion of objects that themselves contain an ObservableColletion.
In my UserControls, I am binding to the properties of my objects where I am using validation (in this example IDataErrorInfo).
The problem is that when I start the program with data already inserted. If the data has few errors, the red validation boxes appear in the correct place (the textboxes where the errors are), but if I have more than a certain number of errors the red boxes start to appear in the top left corner the list container. Can someone explain to me what is happening and how can I solve this problem?

Here is the Code:

```
<Window ...>
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Group}">
            <local:UserControlGroup/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources> 
    <GroupBox Header="Group List">
        <ListBox  BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="4"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </GroupBox>
</window>
```

In the partial class I create 7 similar Objects:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>()
        {
            new Group()
            {
                Name = "Group01",
                Type = "AAAA",
                ItemList = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
                {
                    new Item()
                    {
                        Value1 = -2,
                        Value2 = -1
                    },
                   new Item()
                    {
                        Value1 = -2,
                        Value2 = -1
                    },
                    new Item()
                    {
                        Value1 = -2,
                        Value2 = -1
                    },
                    new Item()
                    {
                        Value1 = -2,
                        Value2 = -1
                    },
                    new Item()
                    {
                        Value1 = -2,
                        Value2 = -1
                    },
                    new Item()
                    {
                        Value1 = -2,
                        Value2 = -1
                    }
                }
            },
            new Group()
            {
                Name = "Group02",
                Type = "BBBB",
                ItemList = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
                {
                    new Item()
                    {
                        Value1 = -2,
            ...
            ...
            new Group()
            {
                Name = "Group07",
                Type = "BBBB",
                ItemList = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
                {
            ...
```

The classes and UserControls:

```
public class Group : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemList { get; set; }
    public string Error => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == nameof(Name))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) return "Value can't be empty.";
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<UserControl ...>
<UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
            <local:UserControlItem/>
        </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
    <GroupBox Header="{Binding Name}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="70" Margin="4" Text="{Binding Type, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</UserControl>
```

```
public class Item : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Error => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == nameof(Value1))
            {
                if (Value1 < 0) return "Value can't be negative.";
            }
            else if (columnName == nameof(Value2))
            {
                if (Value1 < 0) return "Value can't be negative.";
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Width="70" Margin="4" Text="{Binding Value1, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox Width="70" Margin="4" Text="{Binding Value2, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

[Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEChd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what is causing the problem but at least I found a solution using AdornerDecorator's in the TextBox's and defining their margins:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <AdornerDecorator Margin="4">
            <TextBox Width="70" Margin="1" Text="{Binding Value1, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </AdornerDecorator>
        <AdornerDecorator Margin="4">
            <TextBox Width="70" Margin="1" Text="{Binding Value2, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </AdornerDecorator>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```